# send checkbox data along with table data using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following is an inline insert using HTML5 table data to a database table using jQuery and AJAX. I would like to also send a checkbox data along with this table data, how can I achieve that ?

```
<div id="add-product">
<div class="txt-heading">Add Product</div>
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Code</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
                <th style="text-align:right;"><strong>Price</strong></th>
            </tr>   
            <tr><form name="myform"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" id="myCheckboxes" value="someValue2" /></form>
                <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_name"></td>
                <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_code"></td>
                <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_desc"></td>
                <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_price" style="text-align:right;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
<div id="btnSaveAction">Save to Database</div>
</div>



<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("#btnSaveAction").on("click",function(){
    params = ""
    $("td[contentEditable='true']").each(function(){
        if($(this).text() != "") {
            if(params != "") {
                params += "&";
            }
            params += $(this).data('id')+"="+$(this).text();
        }
    });
    if(params!="") {
        $.ajax({
            url: "insert-row.html",
            type: "POST",
            data:params,
            success: function(response){
              $("#ajax-response").append(response);
              $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

code is from [here](https://phppot.com/jquery/inline-insert-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: a `FormData` object might be a cleaner choice than concatenating a string as you do here - then you can use the `set` method to add whatever name/value pairs you want. You can obviously do the same whith string concatenation too. That said, where is the `checkbox`?

Comment: Currently you browse the TD list (which are fillable with the 'contentEditable' option if I understood correctly). You just have to browse the list of CHECKBOX that will be present on the page to add the selected value to your 'params' string, right...?

Comment: @Professor Abronsius, I have added an checkbox in the code. if possible please provide an example. I am new to this... I just want to receive the checkbox data along with other to the insert-row.html

Comment: @Juan, yes, but I am not sure how to properly do that. tried <td contentEditable="false" data-id="product_namee"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes1[]" id="myCheckboxes1" value="someValue3" /></td>, but sems to be not able to read data from the php side

Comment: @bre, I didn't know about the 'contentEditable' attribute for TDs and I find out. But if I understood correctly it's to enter text in the cell. You don't need this attribute on cells containing checkboxes. And you will have to have a loop to read the TDs with 'contentEditable' at ' true'. And another loop to read the Checkboxes

Comment: Just FYI: You **cannot** have a form ( or any element ) at the location you have used, it must either be entirely within a single `table-cell` or the form must completely contain the table! I get errors with the jQuery code when I try to work with it ( I don't use/like jQuery ) but can do this with vanilla Javascript if interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned using a `FormData` object to gather together all the data that you want to send so the following is an example using vanilla Javasript  that does just that.

The `form` **must** be either entirely within a single table-cell or the entire table must be wholly contained within the form for the markup to be valid - hence the form below, with several checkboxes to illustrate the point, contains the table with the `contentEditable` cells.

Any/All checkboxes that are ticked will appear in the POST array - any that remain unticked are ignored. The `set` method of the `FormData` api takes two parameters - a name and value pair. ( a third value is possible if you wish to supply a filename, for an upload for instance )

I appreciate that the question says jQuery but my efforts with that resulted in errors that I knew not how to resolve - hence vanilla JS. The `FormData` object can be used with jQuery quite happily though I believe.

```js
const d=document;

d.querySelector('button[name="save"]').addEventListener('click', e=>{
  // create the FormData object bound to the `form`
  let fd = new FormData( document.forms.myform );
  
  let col=d.querySelectorAll('td[contentEditable="true"]');
  // add all the contentEditable text to the FormData object
  col.forEach(n=>fd.set(n.dataset.id, n.textContent));
  
  // send the http request
  fetch('insert-row.html', { method:'post', body:fd })
    .then( r=>r.text() )
    .then( text=>{
      d.getElementById('ajax-response').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',text);
      col.forEach(n=>n.textContent='')
    })
    .catch(e=>console.log(e))
});
```

```css
body,body *{
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:1rem
}
table{ 
  width:90%;
  border:1px solid grey;
  margin:1rem;
}

tr th:nth-of-type(4),
tr td[contentEditable='true']:nth-of-type(4){
  text-align:right;
}

tr,td{margin:0.1rem;}
td,th{
  padding:0.25rem;
  border:1px solid grey
}

[contentEditable]:focus{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.25)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add-product">
  <div class="txt-heading">Add Product</div>

  
  <form name="myform">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="someValue - 1" />1
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="someValue - 2" />2
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="someValue - 3" />3
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="someValue - 4" />4
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="someValue - 5" />5
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="someValue - 6" />6
    
    <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Code</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
          <th><strong>Price</strong></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_name"></td>
          <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_code"></td>
          <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_desc"></td>
          <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_price"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  
  <button name='save' type='button'>Save to Database</button>
</div>

<div id='ajax-response'></div>
```

---

[image: network request showing checkboxes are present in request]

Comment: Thank you so much for the time and effort. the text content is working, but still I am not able to catch the checkbox data. may be I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Check the console ( network tab ) - any that are checked will be in the POST data if you have done as in that snippet (form containing entire table, named the same and supplied as an argument to FormData )

Comment: If you can see the data in the network tab of the console but you are unable to process it with PHP then you need to look at the PHP code

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius If I understood correctly his form is not validated but it is JQuery code which collects the information to concatenate them in a variable sent to a page. So it must in JQuery collect information from checkboxes no...?

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be this...
If I understood correctly what you were asking.

```
    <div id="add-product">
    <div class="txt-heading">Add Product</div>
        <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Name</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Code</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Description</strong></th>
                    <th style="text-align:right;"><strong>Price</strong></th>
                </tr>   
                <tr><form name="myform"><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" id="myCheckboxes" value="someValue2" /></form>
                    <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_name"></td>
                    <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_code"></td>
                    <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_desc"></td>
                    <td contentEditable="true" data-id="product_price" style="text-align:right;"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="product_xxxx" name="product_xxxx" value="yes"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
    <div id="btnSaveAction">Save to Database</div>
    </div>
    
    
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#btnSaveAction").on("click",function(){
        params = ""
        $("td[contentEditable='true']").each(function(){
            if($(this).text() != "") {
                if(params != "") {
                    params += "&";
                }
                params += $(this).data('id')+"="+$(this).text();
            }
        });
    
        // For each checkbox whose name begins with 'product_'
        $("[type=checkbox][name^='product_']").each(function(){
            
            // If Checkbox Checked
            if($(this).prop('checked')) params += $(this).attr('id')+"="+$(this).val();

    
        });
        // End - For each checkbox whose name begins with 'product_'
    
    
        if(params!="") {
            $.ajax({
                url: "insert-row.html",
                type: "POST",
                data:params,
                success: function(response){
                  $("#ajax-response").append(response);
                  $("td[contentEditable='true']").text("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: if this works, I am supposed to receive data by using `_POST["product_xxxx"]` in `insert-row.html`, right ? the text works, but check boxes are still not sending any data to `insert-row.html`

Comment: @bre ````// If Checkbox Checked
            if($(this).prop('checked')) params += $(this).attr('id')+"="+$(this).val();````. I corrected the code. And yes you must find in your page the value in POST